# Word VBA search for adjacent (non-space) characters with different formatting

Tags: vba, ms-word, format, full-text-search

I need to be able to find every place in my document (hundreds of pages) where there is a formatting change without a space. For example:

> a **bold part**next to regular text

Or red text next to black with no space. I want to have my macro find each "word" (in the vba sense) like this, and execute code based on that character location accordingly. (The loop should identify the character position where the format change occurs... although I can do that part with a loop through the characters within the found word).

Is there a simpler way to do this than by looping character by character through the whole document and checking for a difference in formatting, which would be too resource-intensive?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is it just for bold (& Italic & underline) or are there other formatting changes that need to be checked as well?

Comment: It is not exclusively those, but those are most common (actually, bold or link formatting). They come about because the text is copied from our website, and for some reason, if a line ends with one format and the next line begins with a different format, then no space is copied. The occurrences add up with hundreds of pages!

Comment: So... in your example there is a missing line break between part and next?

Comment: Just a space is missing. I let Word decide where the line breaks should go.

Comment: I was thinking about detecting mixed formatting by making use of wdUndefined (e.g. If .Bold = wdUndefined when passed text is a mixture of Bold and not Bold text). To get efficient detection probably depends a lot on the frequency of items to detect...  You have 100s of pages, approx how many of these detections per page?

Comment: Oh... I'm assuming pages are text only...